# JDBC-JobStoreCMT lock when scheduling

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, quartz-scheduler, weblogic12c

I am using Weblogic + Spring + quartz.

Quartz is configured to use JobStoreCMT.

I noticed that JobStoreCMT is aquireing a DB lock on the quartz tables when jobs are scheduled.

Below is the JobStoreCMT snippet

```
protected Object executeInLock(
        String lockName, 
        TransactionCallback txCallback) throws JobPersistenceException {
    boolean transOwner = false;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        if (lockName != null) {
            // If we aren't using db locks, then delay getting DB connection 
            // until after aquiring the lock since it isn't needed.
            if (getLockHandler().requiresConnection()) {
                conn = getConnection();
            }

            transOwner = getLockHandler().obtainLock(conn, lockName);
        }

        if (conn == null) {
            conn = getConnection();
        }

        return txCallback.execute(conn);
    } finally {
        try {
            releaseLock(conn, LOCK_TRIGGER_ACCESS, transOwner);
        } finally {
            cleanupConnection(conn);
        }
    }
}
```

After this method I see in the quartz tables in the DB inserted the triggers and jobs i scheduled.

My question is why Quartz needs lock on the DB level at this phase ?

I would see a need to have the lock when the jobs are started to be executed , finished etc.

Thanks

Comment: meanwhile i found this : setLockOnInsert

public void setLockOnInsert(boolean lockOnInsert)
Whether or not to obtain locks when inserting new jobs/triggers. Defaults to true, which is safest - some db's (such as MS SQLServer) seem to require this to avoid deadlocks under high load, while others seem to do fine without.
Setting this property to false will provide a significant performance increase during the addition of new jobs and triggers.

Parameters:
lockOnInsert -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some setting which solved my issue:

setLockOnInsert to false because it is true by default.

public void setLockOnInsert(boolean lockOnInsert)

Whether or not to obtain locks when inserting new jobs/triggers. Defaults to true, which is safest - some db's (such as MS SQLServer) seem to require this to avoid deadlocks under high load, while others seem to do fine without.
Setting this property to false will provide a significant performance increase during the addition of new jobs and triggers.

+org.quartz.jobStore.acquireTriggersWithinLock i set it to false (as default ) not to true as i configured initially.